# How to create an associative array from a range in D

Tags: range, associative-array, d, associative

Let's say I have an array of type `Record[]` and I want to create an associative array from it, key being `rec.key`. Is there an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use `std.array`, `std.typecons` and `std.algorithm` libraries and construct this one-liner:

```
Record[Key] assocArray = array.map!( item => tuple( item.key, item ) ).assocArray;
```

It takes `array`, maps it to a tuple `(Key, Record)` and then takes that list of tuples and creates an associative array from it.